# Automatic Report Generation: Quarto Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I'm trying to generate a report. Here's a bareboned file.

"Reference.qmd"

```
name <- c("abc", "def")

for (i in name) {
  rmarkdown::render(input = "example_report.qmd",
                    output_file = paste0("report_", i, "_", Sys.Date(), ".pdf"), 
                    rmarkdown::pdf_document(),
                    params = list(Name = i))
}
```

"example_report.qmd"

```
---
title: "Report for `r params$Name`"
format: html
params:
  Name: "default Name"
---

## Quarto

This is a report for `r params$Name`. This person is fabulous.
```

Output: object 'Name' not found

I've tried doing this in Rmarkdown file and I have got the same error. I have also executed this code from the terminal with the same issue. I've looked at previous solutions but they don't apply to me. Not sure what's incorrect. Need help.

Comment: The params are stored in a `list` named `params`. Hence, to access the value of the parameter `Name` you have use `params$Name`, i.e. try with `\`r params$Name\``.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the text. I had put in `r params$Name`. It's still an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to your questions. One is using the variables from the outer scope of the rmd file. The other is using the params argument to pass the variables to the rmd-file. Only for the first one, I found a solution for quarto, too.

Parameters given to a rmd document through the `params` argument are available inside the document with the list named `params`. for `quarto_render` it looks like this:

```
quarto_render("example_report.qmd",
            output_format = "html",
            output_file = paste0("report_", i, "_", Sys.Date(), ".html"), 
            execute_params=list(Name = i))
```

the qmd or rmd-files has to be changed in the last line:

```
This is a report for `r params$Name`. This person is fabulous.
```

A second way for me was to use the `envir` argument. Here you can simply use the variable name defined as in the outer scope. Here the slighly changed script. You have to rename variables so that the naming matches your rmd-file.

```
x <- c("abc", "def")

for (Name in x) {
    rmarkdown::render(input = "example_report.qmd",
                output_file = paste0("report_", Name, "_", 
    Sys.Date(), "html"), 
                rmarkdown::html_document(),
                envir = parent.frame())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am able to generate output but instead of names, I'm seeing `r params$Name` as title and text. In other words, the names don't seem to be passed to the qmd file. 

Another question I have is regarding the place where I should run the code. I tried running code from another qmd file and an Rscript file. While the output is the same, I'm wondering if there is a place where I should be running the code. 

Also, for the second approach,  I'm getting the title and content as, "Report for default Name".

Comment: My feeling is that rendering a quarto-document inside an other one is quite strange. Seems like there might be a better architecture in your projekt. Why would you render a document inside another one.

Comment: I wasn't able to use the function `quarto_render` to print out the params. What ended up working for me is calling the `rmarkdown::render`. It seems strange but it worked. Thank you!